# Force deletion of a variable in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, memory-management

Okay, so here is my problem :

I have a function that I call very often (several times per second), and a variable `old_date` that is supposed to be computed in the function.
But it seems that this variable is only calculated once, when the function is first called, and then keeps the same value.

Here is the function :

```
def can_push(date):
    """
    Check if the last data was pushed more than TIMEFRAME ago
    :param date: string, date of the new data
    TIMEFRAME = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
    DB = MongoClient(HOST, PORT).database
    DATE_FMT = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
    """

    # If collection doesn't exist, we create it and return True

    out = False
    # Get MongoDB collection
    coll = DB.coll
    # Date of the new data (got through websocket)
    new_date = datetime.strptime(date, DATE_FMT)
    # Date of the last data pushed in DB
    cursor = coll.find().sort('{date:-1}').limit(1)
    old_date = cursor[0]['date']
    print old_date # Format is okay, but date is too old

    if (new_date - old_date) > TIMEFRAME:
        out = True
    # gc.collect()
    del old_date
    return out
```

I tried `del old_date` but it doesn't seem to work.

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python) I tried to use `gc.collect()` but I'm not very familiar with Python so I'm not sure what it really does (and it doesn't appear to work either).

If I connect to MongoDB shell, I can actually check that the last data pushed in the database is way younger than `old_date` shows me.

Does anybody have an idea of another way to forcefully delete `old_date` at the end of the function ?

Python version : 2.7.12
Kernel : Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The old_date is coming from the database, who is writing it to the mongo?

Comment: I am, in an other function. If `can_push` return True, I push my data in the database

Comment: Multithreading? If so check synchronization

Comment: I see two possibilities. There is a problem in the writing, or the mongo drive is kind of caching stuff... I doubt that this has to do with memory or something like that

Comment: Well, I have two websockets and each one is launched with `threading.Thread(...)`, but the data here came from one socket only.

Comment: But the writing and reading happens in the same thread?

Comment: The writting in the DB ? I don't think so, data are correctly pushed. What do you mean by "mongo drive is kind of catching stuff" ?

Comment: Yes, reading and writting for this data are in the same thread

Comment: Caching, it was a typo

Comment: can_push is returning true forever? I don&#39;t know mongo, is the query okay? I suggest you to stop the can_push function after the query, inspect the result and do another queries. You know pdb?

Comment: Ok, I will check for MongoDB settings.

Comment: Yes it always return true, and the query is okay I checked. The debbuger ? Never used it by I go learn right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the error was a typo, my bad.

It should be :

```
cursor = coll.find().sort("date", -1).limit(1)
```

I was conviced that my request was correct since it worked in MongoDB shell.

Sorry for taking your time and thank you for the help !